# Copy Specific Rows Using VB or Macro To Another Sheet, If ANY Date Is Entered

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I perform in a role where we work with cases.

What I would like to do is to run a script based on full pages of data as shown in image one. I would like to copy the lines which contain review dates and copy them into another sheet in the same workbook.

There are teams of staff of usually around 7/8 people. All staff members are on the same workbook.

I am looking to run 1 script which will retreive each case for each staff member (from each individual sheet within the same workbook). Then take all of the rows containing cases to be reviewed and collate all of the data on a seperate sheet.

I'm not expecting anyone to make a code for 8 people, but even if I can be pointed in the right direction this would be excellent.

I realise the data can be filtered before copying across, however all sheets must be locked and the Macro Filter function doesn't appear to work on a locked workbook...

Thanks in advance!

[The original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypM7t.jpg)

[How I want the data to show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUnnX.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us your code attempts?

Answer (score 0):

@Alistair Macintyre........Here is a sample that will loop through the data on 1 sheet.  Now all you need is code that will loop through all of the sheets in the workbook.....Good Luck

```
Sub Move_data()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim ResRow As Integer

    r = 2
    ResRow = 2

    Do Until Len(Trim(Cells(r, 1))) = 0

        DoEvents

        If Len(Trim(Cells(r, 7))) > 0 Then

            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 1) = Trim(Cells(r, 1))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 2) = Trim(Cells(r, 2))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 3) = Trim(Cells(r, 3))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 4) = Trim(Cells(r, 4))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 5) = Trim(Cells(r, 5))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 6) = Trim(Cells(r, 6))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 7) = Trim(Cells(r, 7))
            Worksheets("Review").Cells(ResRow, 8) = Trim(Cells(r, 8))

            ResRow = ResRow + 1

        End If

        r = r + 1

    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```